# What is correct way to solve the build error while making static libraries of Qt

Tags: c++, qt, gcc, build, static-libraries

I am also making static library of Qt (qt.4.3.3) , the steps to do the same are

I downloaded a open source of qt-all-opensource-src-4.3.3. I built static libraries using following steps. The gcc version I am using is gcc 5.2.0

```
cd qt-all-opensource-src-4.3.3
gmake conflcean
./configure -release -static -largefile -qt3support -qt-libpng -qt-libmng -qt-libtiff -qt-libjpeg -glib -platform linux-g++-64 -confirm-license -no-openssl -no-qdbus -prefix ./static_new -prefix-install -opengl -sm -lSM -lICE -xshape -lX11 -xinerama -lXinerama -xcursor -lXcursor -xfixes -lXfixes -xrandr -lXrandr -xrender -lXrender -fontconfig -lfontconfig -tablet -lXi -xkb -glib -lglib-2.0 -lXext -lz -lgthread-2.0
gmake
gmake install
```

I am getting following error message

```
from ../../corelib/codecs/qsimplecodec_p.h:36,
                 from ../../corelib/codecs/qsimplecodec.cpp:22:
../../../include/QtCore/../../src/corelib/thread/qatomic.h: In instantiation of ?QAtomicPointer<T>::QAtomicPointer(T*) [with T = QByteArray]?:
../../corelib/codecs/qsimplecodec.cpp:592:74:   required from here                                                                                                                                                                                                                                  
../../../include/QtCore/../../src/corelib/thread/qatomic.h:190:7: error: ?init? was not declared in this scope, and no declarations were found by argument-dependent lookup at the point of instantiation [-fpermissive]
../../../include/QtCore/../../src/corelib/thread/qatomic.h:190:7: note: declarations in dependent base ?QBasicAtomicPointer<QByteArray>? are not found by unqualified lookup
../../../include/QtCore/../../src/corelib/thread/qatomic.h:190:7: note: use ?this->init? instead
gmake[1]: *** [.obj/release-static/qsimplecodec.o] Error 1
gmake[1]: Leaving directory `/in/inndt69/Projects/oasys/QT/QT/qt-x11-commercial-src-4.3.3/qt-x11-commercial-src-4.3.3/src/tools/rcc'
gmake: *** [sub-rcc-make_default-ordered] Error 2
```

**What is exact cause of this build error?**

I went through [Building Qt-4.3.2 from source on Linux machine](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/31069135/building-qt-4-3-2-from-source-on-linux-machine) but I am not sure if only these two are proper way to solve this problem

A comment from the above answer:

> It gives you a hint what is wrong note: use ‘this->init. This happens with older code using templates not fully qualifying the access to class members with the this-> prefix. Either try to (a) add  `CXXFLAGS='-fpermissive'` to your environment before configuring, or (b) get a newer Qt Version or (c) an older compiler (kidding).

My questions are:

1. What is exact cause of this build error ?
2. I am not sure if compiling Qt code with `CXXFLAGS='-fpermissive` will not cause any side effects in future.?

Comment: This flag allows language errors to be handle by the compiler out of the languages specification, given the compiler supports it. Especially in old code this can happen quite often. Since this is not your codebase and you probably want to keep it original (so no change to the foreign Qt codebase) you are probably best of using just this flag. It does not change code, but just allows some errors regarding the language specs to be compiled as warnings by the compilers exemptions.

Comment: I am not able to get what is cause of the build error ,what is build error mean : ?init? was not declared in this scope, and no declarations were found by argument-dependent lookup at the point of instantiation [-fpermissive] ../../../include/QtCore/../../src/corelib/thread/qatomic.h:

Comment: The cause of the error is that the old Qt version you're using is not valid C++ code. The old compilers in use at the time accepted such invalid C++. New compilers don't. That's all. Why do you insist on using such an old version?